# How can i open a link in a new window in IE8?

Tags: javascript, html

Doing this works in IE7:

```
 <a href="" target="_blank">Link</a>
```

But in IE8 it open a new tab not a new window.
Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you care if it opens a new window? I hate new windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with popups

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function popitup(url) {
newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
return false;
}
```

Then, you link to it by:

```
<a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popitup('popupex.html')">Link to popup</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not codes' problem. You can configure it in IE8:

> Tools->Internet Options->General tab->Tabs section->Settings

Here you can choose to open pop-up in a new window or new tab.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 goes to the tab based (modern) browsers. So default behaviour will always open a tab, not a window. There is no logic in why should a user want to open a page in a window rather than in a tab when clicking a link..

The way to open a window (with several restrictions) is via popup as Ayman suggested - THIS IS TERRIBLE PRACTISE. Almost all browsers will block it by default.